# Take Data From Jenkins Output and Graph/Plot it

Tags: shell, graph, jenkins

I need to pull certain numbers from the console output of a Jenkins build, and then plot that data on a graph. If my output is:

`+ echo -153
-153
+ echo master count: 13596
master count: 13596
Finished: SUCCESS`

I want to pull the master count and -153. The master count is total number of errors while the -153 is the change of errors from two builds. I then want to make a graph using those 2 numbers.

So my question is, how do I send those two sets of data from the console to a graph in jenkins? The numbers will change over time and I wish to be able to see the trend in errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the shell code you listed above is under your control, the easiest way to do this is to echo the output to a CSV file instead of / as well as to the console, and then use the [Jenkins Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) to display the results.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I'm having issues with the Plot Plugin though. I have my csv file in the Jenkins workspace yet nothing will plot. Here is my settings http://imgur.com/MNWU2bk

Comment: I take that back. My script replaced the log file each time and it did not give the plot plugin any new data to plot, so once I changed the shell script to add to the csv file it started plotting correctly.

Comment: Can someone tell me how get the csv file using a shell script to store it in an external database ?

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what the [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) is for.

You need to change your shell build step (or other part of the build) to create
a separate file for each value that you want to plot.
They need to be of the form:

```
YVALUE=<value>
```

In your example you would need a file "mastercount.txt" with:

```
YVALUE=13596
```

and another file called "diffcount.txt" with:

```
YVALUE=-153
```

Then under post-build actions you need to configure the plot-plugin to pick up these files and generate plots.